# Consider the set $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. Find the number of functions from $A\to A$ such that $f(i)\not =i$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

My attempt

The problem can be reduced as distributing 5 elements among 4 elements. The only way to do this is by making groups of $2,1,1,1$

So number of ways are
$$\frac{ 5! \times 4!}{2!\times 1! \times 1! \times 1! \times 3!}$$
$$=240$$
But the answer is $44$

This was just my attempt, which is wrong. What is the correct way to solve it?

Comment: As stated, I would think the answer should be just $4^5 = 1024$.  I would think the 44 answer would be if you also require $f$ to be a permutation (look up "derangements").

Comment: Such a function is called a *derangement*: here is the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement

Comment: "*The problem can be reduced as distributing $5$ elements among $4$ elements*"  I do not believe you understand what the problem is asking for at all.  "*groups of 2,1,1,1*"  You seem to have been thinking of a problem where you are counting the number of surjective functions from $[5]$ to $[4]$ which will indeed have the number you state.  You seem to have ignored the actual statement though... $f(i)\neq i$ for all $i$.  This has the variable as both the input *and as the output*.  You answered the question $f(i)\neq 5$ for all $i$ and unnecessarily added the requirement of surjectivity.

Comment: An example of such functions would be $f(i)=\begin{cases}2&\text{if }i=1\\1&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ since here we have $f(1)\neq 1$ and $f(2)\neq 2$ and $f(3)\neq 3$ etc...   Another example would be $f(i)=\begin{cases}i+1&\text{if }i\leq 4\\ 1&\text{if }i=5\end{cases}$ since here again we have $f(i)\neq i$ for all $i$.  Note that the first is not a bijection from $A$ to $A$ but the second is.

Comment: As for counting where the functions need not be bijections... this is a straightforward application of rule of product.  Choose the output for $1$.  You have $4$ choices.  Choose the output for $2$.  You have $4$ choices.  Continue in this fashion, $4$ options for each of the $5$ outputs, giving a total of $4^5$.  For the more challenging question of counting derangements, see the linked question.

Comment: @JMoravitz that might be true, because I attempted this question in relation to another one which involved finding number of surjective functions. I knew it was wrong but I tired it nonetheless

Comment: @JMoravitz The number of dearragements are indeed 44. But I am still confused as to why number of dearrangements gives the right answer. Is it as simple as the fact $f(i)\not = i$ when in an ideal case it should be?

Comment: I don't understand the question in that last comment.  "*Why number of derangements gives the right answer [to the problem of counting bijective functions $A\to A$ such that $f(i)\neq i$ for all $i$]*"  .... Because that is the **definition** of derangements.  "*Is it as simple as the fact $f(i)\neq i$ when in an ideal case it should be?*"  Ordinarily we don't have such a restriction.  It is not that it *should* be that $f(i)=i$... it is that it can be $f(i)=i$ for some $i$ and $f(i)\neq i$ for others... we don't care!

Comment: Why should the answer be derangements to the problem as written in your post?  It isn't and the answer of $44$ is incorrect to the problem of counting functions in general from $A$ to $A$ satisfying $f(i)\neq i$ for all $i$, as mentioned in the very first comment.  The answer of $44$ is for that question *with the added stipulation that the functions must also be bijective*.  The answer where we did not include that unwritten stipulation is as mentioned already $4^5=1024$

Comment: @JMoravitz let’s assume we need the functions to be bijective. I didn’t understand what you meant by ‘it is that it can be $f(i)=i$...we don’t care!’. Derangements will be give ensure that no elements goes to it stipulated place. My question is, how does the formula know that $f(i)=i$ is the correct place for $i$ to go? Sorry for my rudimentary mathematical language but I really don’t know this topic well

Comment: For ease of notation... I will write a function as a string.  So, $12345$ corresponds to the function $f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x=1\\2&\text{if }x=2\\\vdots\end{cases}$, i.e. $f(x)=x$.  Meanwhile $23451$ corresponds to the function $f(x)=\begin{cases}2&\text{if }x=1\\3&\text{if }x=2\\\vdots\end{cases}$.  Among the derangements are things like $23451,~53124,~31254,\dots$ where no number is in its corresponding position.  $1$ is never in the first position, $2$ is never in the second position, etc... and further each number is used exactly once...

Comment: Functions like $21111$ also satisfy that no number is in its corresponding position, however functions like this happen to not satisfy the property that every number is used exactly once.  Functions like $12543$ are not derangements because $1$ happened to be in the first position.  That is a perfectly valid function... just not one that we wanted to count in this problem

Comment: "*How does the formula know that $f(i)=i$ is the correct place for $i$ to go?*"  Nowhere did we ever talk about the functions where $f(i)=i$ for all $i$.  There is only one such function... the identity function $12345$.  "*When in an ideal case it should be*"  Nowhere did anyone ever say that it *should* be that $f(i)=i$ for all $i$ or even for some $i$... just that in normal counting problems we might not *care* whether $f(i)=i$ or not for certain $i$.  They might be, they might all be, some might not be, all might not be, there can be a mix and unless specified we don't care